# Collar definitions are equivalent in metric space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

There are two different definitions used for collars in a topological space $X$, the one used in [Locally flat imbeddings of topological manifolds, Brown, 1962](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970177), and the one used in [A new proof of Brown's collaring theorem, Connelly, 1971](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2037284). Connelly claims that these definitions are equivalent when $X$ is metrizable and the collared subset $X'$ is closed in $X$. How to show that?

### Definitions

A subset $X' \subset X$ is *Brown-collared* in $X$, if there exists an open embedding $h' : X' \times [0, 1) \to X$, such that

- $h'(x, 0) = x$.

A subset $X' \subset X$ is *Connelly-collared* in $X$, if there exists a closed embedding $h : X' \times [0, 1] \to X$, such that

- $h|(X' \times [0, 1))$ is an open embedding,
- $h(x, 0) = x$.

### Some examples

For this question we will assume that $X'$ is closed in $X$, since being Connelly-collared implies that. Let $X = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq 0\}$, and $X' = (0, 1) \times \{0\}$. Let $h' : X' \times [0, 1) \to X$ be such that $h'((x, 0), t) = (x, t)$. Then $h'$ is a Brown-collar of $X'$ in $X$. However, $X'$ is not Connelly-collared in $X$, since $X'$ is not closed in $X$.

Let $X = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq 0\}$, and $X' = [0, 1] \times \{0\}$. Let $h : X' \times [0, 1] \to X$ be such that $h((x, 0), t) = (x, t)$. Then $h$ is not a Connelly-collar of $X'$ in $X$, since $h(X' \times [0, 1))$ is not open in $X$.

Let $X = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq 0\} \setminus \{(0, 0), (1, 0)\}$ (where the latter set contains two points), and $X' = (0, 1) \times \{0\}$. Let $h : X' \times [0, 1] \to X$ be such that $h((x, 0), t) = (x, (0.5 - |x - 0.5|)t)$. Then $h$ is a Connelly-collar of $X'$ in $X$.

### Connelly $\implies$ Brown

Clearly $h' = h|(X' \times [0, 1))$ is a Brown-collar of $X'$.

### Connelly $\impliedby$ Brown

My idea was to study the function

$h(x, t) = h'(x, t/2)$

It is then not hard to show that $h$ is an embedding, $h|(X' \times [0, 1))$ is an open embedding, and $h(x, 0) = x$. The problematic part is to show that $h$ is closed.

Edit: Moishe Kohan's counter-example below shows that when $h$ is defined this way, it may not be closed. Some other strategies are needed.

Comment: Do you assume that $X'$ is a closed subset of $X$? Otherwise, the claim clearly fails.

Comment: Yes! $X'$ must be assumed closed; edited the question. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: OK, but one can also show that proposed map does not work in general (unless you assume $X'$ compact, of course, which might be what Connelly assumes). It is still possible that there is a totally different Connelly-collaring map ...

Comment: How do you show that the $h'(x, t/2)$ map is not in general a Connelly-collar (i.e. is not closed)? (Yes, compactness surely suffices to show closedness.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which shows that the construction (Brown$\Rightarrow$Connelly) described in your question cannot work. Consider the rectangle $X=\{(x,y): 0\le y\le 1, -1<x<1\}$, and let 
$X'=X\cap \{(x,0): x\in {\mathbb R}\}$ be the intersection of $X$ with the x-axis.

Consider the triangle $T$ in $X$ with the vertices $(-1,0), (1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and with the two upper sides removed (but we retain the bottom open side, equal to $X'$).

Then $T$ is a collar of $X'$ in $X$, in the sense of Brown, with the homeomorphism 
$$
h: X'\times [0,1)\to T
$$
sending each slice $X'\times \{t\}$ homeomorphically (actually, linearly) to the horizontal open line segment 
$$
H_t=\{(x,y): y= t\}\cap T. 
$$
(Such a homeomorphism $h$ does exist, I will leave an explicit formula to you to work out.)

However, while $X'$ is closed in $X$, the restriction of $h$ to $X'\times [0,s]$ is not a closed map for all $s\in (0,1)$, since $H_t$ is not closed in $X$.

Comment: This is a beautiful counter-example for showing that $h'(x, t/2)$ does not work globally. Good thinking! (As a side-note, this does not affect the partial result because it obtains merely local Connelly-collars from $h'(x, t/2)$, and then puts them back together to obtain some other Connelly-collar.)